# ERROR: for redis Cannot create container for service redis: source is not directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Can anyone help ?

Everytime i try to bring up redis so i connect my app that i am writing it gives the error

> ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis: source is
>   not directory

I created a simple dockerfile like so

```
FROM redis:5-alpine
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

and my compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    container_name: "redis"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

    volumes:
      - redis-data:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

    networks:
      - internal

    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  redis-data:

networks:
  internal:
    external: false
```

I tried removing the COPY command in the dockerfile and it built the container. Also tried removing the Volumes in the compose file and it also built the container.

So its something to do with this but I just can't see it.

Could anyone help ?

I know its something stupid I have done.

The files are all in the same directory

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in docker-compose

```
 volumes:
      - redis-data:/usr/local/etc/redis
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that :-) It works. Thanks again.